# Python string.replace equivalent (from Javascript)

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I am trying to pick up python and as someone coming from Javascript I haven't really been able to understand python's regex package re

What I am trying to do is something I have done in javascript to build a very very simple templating "engine" (I understand AST is the way to go for anything more complex):

In javascript:

```
var rawString = 
  "{{prefix_HelloWorld}}   testing this. {{_thiswillNotMatch}} \ 
  {{prefix_Okay}}";

rawString.replace(
   /\{\{prefix_(.+?)\}\}/g,
   function(match, innerCapture){
     return "One To Rule All";
});
```

In Javascript that will result in:

> "One To Rule All   testing this. {{_thiswillNotMatch}}        One To
>   Rule All"

And the function will get called twice with:

```
   innerCapture === "HelloWorld"
   match ==== "{{prefix_HelloWorld}}"
```

and:

```
   innerCapture === "Okay"
   match ==== "{{prefix_Okay}}"
```

Now, in python I have tried looking up docs on the re package

```
import re
```

Have tried doing something along the lines of:

```
match = re.search(r'pattern', string)
if match:
  print match.group()
  print match.group(1)
```

But it really doesn't make sense to me and doesn't work. For one, I'm not clear on what this group() concept means? And how am I to know if there is match.group(n)... group(n+11000)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's `re.sub` function is just like JavaScript's `String.prototype.replace`:

```
import re

def replacer(match):
    return match.group(1).upper()

rawString = "{{prefix_HelloWorld}}   testing this. {{_thiswillNotMatch}} {{prefix_Okay}}"
result = re.sub(r'\{\{prefix_(.+?)\}\}', replacer, rawString)
```

And the result:

```
'HELLOWORLD   testing this. {{_thiswillNotMatch}} OKAY'
```

As for the groups, notice how your replacement function accepts a `match` argument and an `innerCapture` argument. The first argument is `match.group(0)`. The second one is `match.group(1)`.

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense. What would group 2, 3, etc be? Or are those not defined.

Comment: @JohnTomson: `.group(n)` is the nth capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to substitute all occurrences of {{prefix_*}} where * is basically anything. If so, this code works and is simple.

```
 pattern = "\{\{prefix_.*?\}\}"
 re.sub(pattern, "One To Rule All", rawString)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using the same pattern more than once (such as in a loop), then this is better:

```
pattern = re.compile("\{\{prefix_.*?\}\}")
# ... later ...
pattern.sub("One To Rule All", rawString)
```